# When is the cordova http cache cleared?

Tags: cordova

Can't find any info on the http cache for Cordova apps.

When is the private and public cached cleared?  From my testing, both caches are cleared after a full close of the app and re-open.  Is this a correct understanding?

Is there any way to retain the http public cache between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solid answer, but... Testing with my remotely hosted app that has a large bundle to download, it takes several seconds on first launch to download and start the web app. After completely stopping the app and starting it again, the web app starts much faster. This occurs on both Android and iOS.

On Android, clearing the app's data causes the app to start slowly again.

Somewhat related, the OS may clear WebView caches and localstorage at any point while the app is not in use. You should use more persistent native storage for anything more important. e.g. use the [cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) plugin.